# How to keep listening to sockets, android

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

I am creating an app and its updating its data using a

```
sockets.on("new data", getDate);
```

listener. However, when my server emits "new data" the is nothing listened. To be specific about this. I created a foregroundServiceClass extends Service, which is responsible for the sockets communication with the server. But when listening, I have to add the on listener after emitting and cannot receive lonely emissions from the server. Thanks.

Comment: It would be easy if you can share the code

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the socket connection.

Comment: Check out my answer, +1, also, I need to mark it as solved after 2 days. can you post the answer instead.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the solution was to add socket.broadcast.emit() in the node js server instead of socket.emit().

I hope it solves someone's problem someday.